# Read Object from JSON web page in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I want to read some List<> of Object from a JSON file, which is generated by a PHP file.
When I try to compile it, I have some problems, it seems that the Smartphone is waiting something. Also I'm not sure if the read is correct for Windows Phone. Thank you in advance for your help !
This is the JSON file example:

```
{"giocatori":[{"Giocatore":"124","Cognome":"DE SANCTIS","Ruolo":"P","Squadra":"ROM"},{"Giocatore":"140","Cognome":"MIRANTE","Ruolo":"P","Squadra":"PAR"},{"Giocatore":"156","Cognome":"SKORUPSKI","Ruolo":"P","Squadra":"ROM"}],"success":1}
```

These are the Objects:

```
public class Giocatori
{
    public string Giocatore { get; set; }
    public string Cognome { get; set; }
    public string Ruolo { get; set; }
    public string Squadra { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Giocatore + " " + Cognome + " " + Ruolo + " " + Squadra;
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Giocatori> giocatori { get; set; }
    public int success { get; set; }
}
```

And here are the methods:

```
 private async Task<RootObject> getPlayers()
    {
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri("myURL");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(serviceUri);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)); 
        RootObject RootObject = new RootObject();
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(RootObject.GetType()); 
        RootObject = ser.ReadObject(ms) as RootObject;
        return RootObject;
    }

    private void loadPlayers()
    {
        RootObject players =  getPlayers().Result;
        setComboboxs(players.giocatori); // The method which I need to use the 
    }
```

Comment: This question has been asked a lot. I would suggest you look at JSON.Net and the website http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I follow that site for generates the data, and I can read from JSON in C# for Desktop, but not in Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download JSON.Net package via Nuget.

Right Click project > Manage Nuget > Json.net > Install

[image]

According to http://json2csharp.com/ your class should look like this.

```
public class Giocatori
    {
        public string Giocatore { get; set; }
        public string Cognome { get; set; }
        public string Ruolo { get; set; }
        public string Squadra { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Giocatori> giocatori { get; set; }
        public int success { get; set; }
    }
```

RootObject can be renamed to whatever you like.

When you receive your JSON do

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("jsonstring");
```

Comment: JSonConvert method is not recognized in Windows Phone 8.1. This method works in C# for Desktop application. I think the problem isn't about the Deserialize process, but how to retrive the result of the task.

Comment: I'm developing a WP8.1 app myself believe me the library does work. 
Make sure you downloaded the nuget package first and add the import 
using Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: You're right. The problem was about the fact I need to install for each project the library. Now the Method is well get by the IDE. Now I need to understand how to you the asyn method correctly. Any hints ?

Comment: Accept this answer and ask a new question on stackoverflow

Comment: I accept, but I think the question can be ansered directly from here, without going out of the topic.